# Paraview: Calculate the surfae area of a3D object

Tags: surface, paraview

I want to calculate the surface area of a 3D body (binarized: 1=inside, 0=outside so it's "voxelated") using Paraview. I found the filter "integrate variable" that gives me a value and it's reasonable. But I want to know what's the algorithm implemented into Paraview to compute it! It's an open-source software so everything should be open but I cannot find the reference.
Any idea?

Comment: You can always look at the code :-) The filter exposes the vtkIntegrateAttributes filter in ParaView:

http://www.paraview.org/gitweb?p=ParaView.git;a=blob;f=ParaViewCore/ServerManager/SMApplication/Resources/filters.xml;h=9c889f296b79bff80a0af223a11291ce73c79291;hb=HEAD

vtkIntegrateAttributes source code is browsable at

http://www.paraview.org/gitweb?p=ParaView.git;a=blob;f=ParaViewCore/VTKExtensions/Default/vtkIntegrateAttributes.cxx;h=352155009780b7a45d5b4c00a75178de0f724675;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple: this filter computes the area of each polygon and sums them up. There are quite a few types of polygons supported, so the details of computing the area of each vary. Please consult http://www.paraview.org/gitweb?p=ParaView.git;a=blob;f=ParaViewCore/VTKExtensions/Default/vtkIntegrateAttributes.cxx;h=352155009780b7a45d5b4c00a75178de0f724675;hb=HEAD for details.

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me in this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917186/paraview-how-to-draw-a-vector