# Paraview: How to draw a vector?

Tags: paraview

I have a 3D body that I use to visualize in Paraview. I just want to draw a vector: I know its components and the application point (the baricenter of my body, I know the coordinates). 
Is it possible?

Comment: You could wrap something like this in a Paraview plugin: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/OrientedArrow - it's unfortunately that things like this aren't supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to represent the vector? With an arrow? Please see the Arrow source in the Sources menu. You may change the orientation using the Orientation settings under the Properties tab. Note that the Orientation values are rotations about the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis. There is nothing out of the box that you can plug the vector components into.